# Is this an F# compiler bug? #2

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, ienumerable, for-loop

```
open System

type Foo() =
     interface Collections.IEnumerable with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null

type Bar() =
     interface Collections.IEnumerable with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null
     interface Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> with
         member x.GetEnumerator () = null

let xs, ys = Foo(), Bar()

for x in xs do () // <--
for y in ys do () // fine
```

The code above produces the following compilation error:

`The type 'Foo' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax, i.e. is not compatible with either seq<_>, IEnumerable<_> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method.`

The code looks perfectly legal and the generic version works fine. Is this an F# compiler bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a mismatch between the  error message an the specification. As *kvb* points out, the specification allows `for ... in` in only two cases:

- When the type implements generic `IEnumerable<_>` interface (aka `seq<_>`)
- When the type has a `GetEnumerator` method that returns type with certain properties

If the type *implements* a non-generic `IEnumerable` interface then it doesn't match any of the two conditions. However, if you cast it to `IEnumerable` then it will actually be the `IEnumerable` type, which matches the second condition. Having a `GetEnumerator` member directly in the type (as desco suggests) is also correct, because it also matches the second case.

So, I think that the error message is incorrect, because it says that implementing non-generic `IEnumerable` is sufficient, but it is actually not.

However, there seems to be one actual compiler error related to the `for` loop. You get a compiler "internal error" when you write the following code (which is not correct, because the inferred generic return type doesn't implement `IEnumerator`):

```
 type Foo() =
   member x.GetEnumerator () = null
 for x in Foo() do ()  // Internal error here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tomas! actually I've found this bug and submit it to fsbugs@microsoft.com a hour ago...

Comment: @ControlFlow: Ah, surely they'll fix it more promptly if they receive two reports in a single hour :-)!

Answer (score 5):

your sample can be simplified to

```
type Foo() =
 interface Collections.IEnumerable with
     member x.GetEnumerator () = null

for x in Foo() do ()
```

Initially F# compiler tries to assert that source type is implementing IEnumerable <_>
After this assertion is failed - it searches accessible GetEnumerator/0 method that returns type with accessible MoveNext()/Current members. Seems that methods from explicit implementation of IEnumerable are are not visible in the Foo type, because code below is valid:

```
open System
open System.Collections

type Foo() =
    member x.GetEnumerator () : IEnumerator = null

for x in Foo() do () // GetEnumerator is accessible in Foo
```

or

```
open System
open System.Collections

type Foo() =
    interface IEnumerable with
        member x.GetEnumerator () : IEnumerator = null

for x in (Foo() :> IEnumerable) do () // IEnumerable has accessible GetEnumerator
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, but it's not a very helpful error message.  See the [Sequence Iteration Expressions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597471) section of the spec for the details on how `for ... in ... do ...` expressions are evaluated.  If the type implements `IEnumerable<_>`, the pattern just works as expected.  Otherwise, the compiler looks for a public (the spec says "accessible") `GetEnumerator` method with the right signature and calls that.  Because F# interface implementations are explicit, the `GetEnumerator` method isn't available without upcasting your `Foo` type to `IEnumerable`.  If you perform the upcast, your code again works as expected:

```
for x in (xs :> Collections.IEnumerable) do () // fine
```